# Display only one bar produced by a bar chart

Tags: sas

Is there a way to only show one of the bars produced by sgplot vbar? For example,

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.birthwgt;
vbar married / stat=percent;
run;
```

returns this plot:

[image]

but I want this (photoshopped):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xaxis` statement `values=` option.

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 100;
    if id < 35 then married='Yes'; else married = 'No';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  vbar married / stat=percent;
  xaxis values=('Yes');              * <---------------;
run;
```

[image]